# Mysql create tables like other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, create-table

I have 5 databases(or schemas) which have more than 100 tables in MySQL and now I need to create new database which have tables like older tables.
New tables' names are in this format

> **"OldDatabaseName"_"OldTableName"_History**

and their columns are almost same, just I need to add 2 new columns like **START** and **END** timestamps for every table.

There won't be any foreign keys in new tables, and also not any auto increment column, just ***ID and START*** columns will be unique key.

So, What kind of SQL do I need to use for this purpose?

Comment: Lesson 1: Have a script file for each database/schema to be able to re-create or create copy db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Are there any loop through solution for this?"
Yes.

write a stored procedure and:

- Declare Variables, Cursor and Exception_Handler (we use the Exception_Handler to find an exit point for our loop)
- load all schema_names/table_names from information_schema.tables that
  should be duplicated into the cursor (the cursor allows us to fetch the
  data into variables so we can use them in our statements).
- after that you can use the schema_names/table_names in a loop to create a 
  copy of every table in the new schema. just fetch the schema_name and 
  table_name into variables and use prepared statements to create your 
  tables. with every run-through a table will be created from inside the 
  loop. Once all tables have been created an exception will occur to tell 
  you that there is no more data.

as people have pointed out:

- empty tables without keys :

  ```
  create table new_schema_name.new_table_name 
  select * from old_schema_name.old_table_name limit 0;
  ```
- filled tables without keys (includes all data of the original table) :

  ```
  create table new_schema_name.new_table_name
  select * from old_schema_name.old_table_name;
  ```
- empty table with all properties of the original table (in case its needed):

  ```
  create table new_schema_name.new_table_name 
  like old_schema_name.old_table_name ;
  ```

in case you have small tables (<5 million records [also depends on hardware]) and you don't want to repeat this job, you can use a GUI to copy the tables by drag and drop. Navicat for MySQL supports this function.
after that you can use a texteditor + excel to build your alter commands to adjust the table names and add the new columns. the list of table_names for that can be selected from information_schema.tables.
this will take much more time than running the procedure but should still be faster for beginners compared to writing and testing the procedure.

i recommend the stored procedure approach

Answer (score 1):

first create the table using this one

```
create table new_table select * from old_table;
```

and then use alter table query to alter your wish

Comment: Are there any loop through solution for this? I mean like get all schemas and for each table in those schemas run this line of sql?

Comment: Careful, thiis won't duplicate PK, FK and indexes from original table (at least with MyISAM)

Comment: @Preuk actually that is exactly what I want, thanks for warning

Answer (score 1):

Given recent comments, the best answer seems to be to dump the table using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-syntax), modify the table name in the output before committing the `CREATE TABLE`and `INSERT` again. Then you can `ALTER TABLE` and `UPDATE` this new tablea to your liking.